# Performance issue while LayoutTransform is applied to DataGridCell content

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a custom datagrid whose cell is styled as below

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyleBase"
           TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.Header.CellBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Text}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellHorzontalAlignment}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellFontWeight}"
                                   Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Margin}"
                                   Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Padding}" />
                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The datagrid is styled as below

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <!-- This is needed to force DG to have a non-default value.  Otherwise the DGR.DetailsVisibility cannot have a value of VisibleWhenSelected by default. -->
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode"
                Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode"
                Value="Recycling" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="EnableColumnVirtualization"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="CellStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource CellStyleBase}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false"
                                      Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!--Left Column Header Corner -->
                                        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HeaderBorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                                                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HeaderBackground}"
                                                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"
                                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                        <!--Column Headers-->
                                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                                        Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                        Visibility="Visible">
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                                                                <Border Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=NameHeaderBackground}">
                                                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                                        </Setter.Value>
                                                    </Setter>
                                                </Style>
                                            </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.Style>
                                        </DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>

                                        <!--Column Header Splitter-->
                                        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                      Height="4"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=NameHeaderBackground}"
                                                      Foreground="Transparent"
                                                      Cursor="SizeWE" />

                                        <!-- Line separates the column header with the content-->
                                        <Canvas Grid.Row="1"
                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                Height="1.5"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                                Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomDataGrid}}, Path=HorizontalGridLinesBrush}" />


                                        <!--DataGrid content-->
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                                Grid.Row="2"
                                                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                                CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                                        <ScrollBar Grid.Row="0"
                                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                                   Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                                   Orientation="Vertical"
                                                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                                   Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />

                                        <Grid Grid.Row="3"
                                              Grid.Column="1">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1"
                                                       Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                                       Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="DG_ScrollViewer"
                                 Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                                 Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="IsShowingHorizontalScrollBar"
                                    Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the datagrid, rows will be dynamically added using a background thread and it can contain thousands of data. There is a performance issue with the datagrid. CPU usage keeps on increasing.

I found out that the reason is `LayoutTransform`. If I set the `Height` of the `DataGridCell` or `Width` of the `Grid` which is the content of the cell, the CPU usage will be reduced. But I cannot hardcode the same. The width should be set based on the length of the content.

Setting hardcoded height:

```
<Setter Property="Height"
            Value="50" />
```

Setting hardcoded width:

```
<Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    Width="50">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Text}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellHorzontalAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellFontWeight}"
        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Margin}"
        Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Padding}" />
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Grid>
```

First, I tried binding a converter to which content is passed and width is calculated and returned to `Width` property of `Grid`. This causes a flickering while new data is added and the CPU usage will be increased.

```
<Grid x:Name="BackgroundGrid"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    Width="{Binding Path=Content.Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Text}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellHorzontalAlignment}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Column.Header.CellFontWeight}"
        Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Margin}"
        Padding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},Path=Content.Padding}" />
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
</Grid>
```

Second, I replaced `LayoutTransform` with `RenderTransform`. The width of the cell will not increase based on the content which will result in showing only part of the data.

Third, I tried binding a property to `Height` of `DataGridCell` which is updated dynamically with highest width of the value in the `DataGridCell`. This is also consuming CPU usage.

Is there any other alternative to achieve the result of `LayoutTransform` other than `RenderTransform`?

Looking forward to any kind of input/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Is getting your cell text at 90deg all you're trying to do here? If so, why not apply one transform to the whole grid instead of every individual cell?

Comment: @Chris W  : Appreciate your response. If you look at the style of the datagrid, you can see that its transformed too. The requirement can be achieved only if I transform both datagrid and cell.

Comment: The reason why LayoutTransform causes high CPU is because any change in layout requires an entire layout pass - all cells will have to recalculate their width and height. If you fix the width/height to a specific size, then there is less calculation involved (doesn't have to measure content etc). The DataGrid impelementation is mega slow in regards to the layout pass. RenderTransform will simply render the pixels differently, no layout change involved, thus the better performance. As for your actual question - how to alternatively achieve the same result - that I don't know...

Comment: @Marko : Thanks for your response. I too couldn't find out an alternative solution. However, the CPU usage is decreased to an extent by setting the height/width.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making the transform happen in the rendering logic itself. I haven't tried this myself but I think it is worth a shot to see if this would give similar performance to using `RenderTransform` while also giving you the result that you are looking for if you use `RotatedText` in place of your `TextBlock` with the `LayoutTransform`:

```
public class RotatedText : FrameworkElement
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var ft = new FormattedText(Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Calibri"), 12, Brushes.Black);

        drawingContext.PushTransform(new RotateTransform(-90, 0, ft.Width));
        drawingContext.DrawText(ft, new Point(0, ft.Width));
        drawingContext.Pop();

        Width = ft.Height;
        Height = ft.Width;
    }
}
```